# Need MySQL query for updating table

Tags: mysql

Here is my table structure

```
 CREATE TABLE emp
 (
      id INT,
      name VARCHAR(25),
      salary INT,
      joining_date DATE
 )
```

I want a SQL query to update salary +1500 if joining_date is less than '2014-04-14' in MySQL.

Comment: Sorry this is not a place where you can demand free coding

Comment: `UPDATE emp SET salary = salary + 1500 WHERE joining_date < '2014-04-14'`

Comment: Please go to this website and learn it http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is asking for homework.

Comment: @ElzoValugi It is not a off-topic question.  I just want to confirm the query and will use it in a different context. And also it is not my homework and all StackOverflow users will not always ask for help only for homework. They face different problems so they ask questions

Comment: It may not look to you, but this way of asking question can lead to thousands of unanswered questions and to a category of users that will never research and never learn. It is much easier to ask someone, this is why we are asking you, a new member, to read this help pages, and understand a little better how this site is organized: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
update emp
set salary = salary + 1500
where joining_date < '2014-04-14'
```

Comment: Yes I need that . Will it work?